# access components values using Joomla 1.5 plugin onAfterRender

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

can I access Component value from Plugin onAfterRender ? If yes , how do I do it ? I am using Joomla 1.5.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What do you mean by "component value"?

Comment: example in my view.html.php I have $this->assign('name', 'John');.. then in my plugin, onAfterRender I want to access the name using $this->get('name');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->assign('name', 'John');
```

This line just passes the string 'John' from the view to the layout, it has nothing to do with any plugin. If you work onnAfterRender and want to get certain info from the page about to be displayed, you could try search for it through the renderd content, ehich can be accessed using

```
JResponse::getBody();
```

if you want to replace some info on the page, do that and, at the end of the plugin, "rewrite" the page

```
JResponse::setBody($yourData);
```